# Looking for Alternative to TortoiseHG under Win32

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, screen-readers

I'm looking for an alternative GUI client for Mercurial that works on Win32 and that is accessible to a screen reader, specifically, JAWS for Windows.  TortoiseHG doesn't work for me because of its reliance on GTK/Tkinter under Python.  Something programmed in WXPython (or any other WX equivalent), as well as any app programmed using standard Windows controls, will work for me.  I already use TortoiseSVN, and that app is quite accessible, if that helps any.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used a screen reader, so this might be a stupid idea... :-) But from what I can read on Wikipedia, I get the impression that the command line Mercurial client might be a better source than a GUI client?

If it gives too much textual output for a screen reader to read aloud comfortably, then maybe you can solve that by using the template system built into Mercurial. There is a ready-made style called "compact", which you can use like this:

```
% hg log --limit 2 --style compact
9366[tip]   9ff178e7b627   2009-08-18 22:07 -0400   greg-hg
  tags: don't crash if unable to write tag cache

9365   b8dc3eba4f9d   2009-08-19 12:51 +0200   dirkjan
  mq: get rid of qnext, qprev and qtop
```

For comparison, the normal output looks like this:

```
% hg log --limit 2
changeset:   9366:9ff178e7b627
tag:         tip
user:        Greg Ward 
date:        Tue Aug 18 22:07:43 2009 -0400
summary:     tags: don't crash if unable to write tag cache

changeset:   9365:b8dc3eba4f9d
user:        Dirkjan Ochtman 
date:        Wed Aug 19 12:51:07 2009 +0200
summary:     mq: get rid of qnext, qprev and qtop
```

I don't know of any other styles, but you can try asking on the [mailing lists](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MailingLists).

Answer (score 0):

Try HgWin:

http://bitbucket.org/zzsergant/hgwin

Note that TortoiseHG is currently [being reworked to be based on Qt](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/Home), so if you're already happy with it and can get by for now, the problem will hopefully resolve itself in time.